# How do I stop editable cells to be pushed to the left? Or how do I get the width of the editable marks?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

If you make a `tableVIew` `cell` editable so that you can rearrange the order of the `cells` these hold-and-drag marks appear in the `cells`:

[image]

Great, but the downside is that they push the whole `cell` to the left, so the `auto layout` that is supposed to put things in the middle doesn't work the way I intend. Labels that I want to be in the middle are now a bit to the left. Even if I constrain things to the `cell` itself I get the same result since it appears that the whole cell is pushed.

Is there a way to get the `width` of the edit-marks (not sure about the technical term for it) so that I can take that into account when setting up the `auto layout`? Or is there another way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not widely published as far as I know. You could try setting the layout margins within the cell to offset the displacement from the reorder view?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 40, bottom: 0, right: 10)

    return cell
}
```

40 seems to be the magic number but you could amend with a bit of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks. You're sure 40 is the width of the edit thingy? Seems like a good number but is it exact? No way to get ahold of the width property?